# eclipse 4.28; pydev 11.0.1; python 3.12; jdk 17

Tags: eclipse, installation, pydev, python-3.12

I'm woking with windows 10 and Linux Min 21 - Both the same.
When istalling via Marketplace or "install new Software", there´s always the message:
"The following solutions are not available: PyDev - Python IDE for Eclipse 11.0.1 (id=org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature.feature.group, eclipse -> new software: https://www.pydev.org/updates/)".

Is there any fix or workaround to get an editor belonging to that package?

I tried almost everything in Eclipse. I used the expected Versions.
python, pip, virtualenv, ... everything works, but PyDev.

ThanX

Answer (score 0):

Humm, the mylyn integration is no longer available, so you should uncheck the `org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature` when installing PyDev (see the image below).

I'll take a look into updating the Eclipse Marketplace so that it doesn't appear anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a fresh installed eclipse (Version 2023-09 (4.29.0) Build id: 2023-09-07-1323). When I tried to install PyDev via Marketplace or "Install new software" PyDev asked me to login at github:
[github_login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0qrU.png)

A working solution is to install PyDev via the zip-file provided at sourceforge as  discribed at [pydev_install](https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)